# How to save multiple django form in one page with one submit button

Tags: django, forms

i'm new when developing django. I have some question after days by days finding the answer. Here the go.

1. What i want is making ajax form that handle 2 model form, with 1 submit button
2. I can already saved the data in each form, **but got problem in foreign key field got None instead**

Here we go my model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     info = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
      
     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ModelB(models.Model):

    xmodel = models.ForeignKey(to=ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modelX', blank=True, null=True)
    no_1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    no_2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

Form Class:

```
class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = ModelA
      fields = '__all__'

class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = ModelB
      exclude = ('xmodel',)
```

View class:

```
def AddData(request):
    tpl = 'add.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
      mdla = ModelAForm(request.POST)
      mdlb = ModelBForm(request.POST)

      if mdla.is_valid():
         obj = mdla.save()

         if mdlb.is_valid():
            mdlb.save(commit=False)
            mdlb.xmodel=obj
            mdlb.save()

    else:
      mdla = ModelAForm()
      mdlb = ModelbForm()
```

In TPL i'm using ajax to send, it can save model a and model b, but in modelb xmodel (foreign key) it got None when check in adminpanel.

Which i do wrong, how to make it happen when handling the forms?

Comment: Should  `mdlb = ModelBForm(request.POST)` be after `obj = mdla.save()`?

Comment: i think, there is no different doing it. correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For people that got something like me, using 2 form.

i've solved my problem with this logic.

1. Create object manually
2. Initiatite form with instance new object
3. save

for above problem:

```
def AddData(request):
    tpl = 'add.html'
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mdla = ModelAForm(request.POST)

        if mdla.is_valid():
            obj = mdla.save()

            newObj = ModelB.objects.create(xmodel=obj)

            mdlb = ModelBForm(request.POST, instance=newObj)
            if mdlb.is_valid():
                mdlb.save()
    else:
        mdla = ModalAForm()
        mdlb = ModalBForm
```

This is solution i get, if anyone could do better please tell me. Thankx